# Spark avoid distributing small dataframe across multiple nodes

Tags: performance, apache-spark, hadoop, scheduler, partition

I have small summary dataframes `df_var` (10+ columns, around 30 rows) that keeps changing in a loop, then joined with a big data set df

```
df = spark.sql("select * from my_table")
for iter in range(0,num_iter):
   for v in var_list:
     //....
     //Operations here that changes df
     df_var = f1(df_var, ...)
     df = f2(...)
     ..
     df = join(df, df_var)
```

My loop is performing slowly with a typical timeline like this

[image]

I would like to ask :

1. I see a lot of shuffling concerning `df` and `df_var` in the execution plan, and would like to avoid them. For df, I `repartition` them into 5-10 partitions. For small dataframe df_var, how should I deal with them ? Is there a way to put them into a single node to avoid shuffling every loop ?
2. `Scheduler Delay` and `Task Deserialization Time` are significant. How can we tackle this ?

Comment: Since you mentioned that one of the table is smaller, you might want to consider broadcast join

Comment: What is a max value of num_iter? Maybe instead of doing num_iter joins to df, at first create dataFrame df_var_total that contains all mutation of the df_var, with additional column "iteration_number" and make one join to this table? 

If num_tier is not very big, than you can *broadcast* df_var_total to all the nodes.

Comment: num_iter max at 10. I'd wish to have all df_var before hand, but unfortunately the logic does not give that. More precisely, df_var =f1(last df, last df_var), df=df.join(current df_var) at each loop.  It's iteration until convergence, df_var and df is updated at each loop and checked if they stabilize (hence also max num_iter to avoid infinite loop and/or divergence; it's actually a while loop but for the sake of simplicity, I put here as for). Result has to be ready for next loop, lazy evaluation do-all-joins-at-the-end is unlikely. Any take on scheduler delay and deserialization time?